# How to fix mis-aligned arraylist display using for loop

Tags: java

Hello can you help me with my code, when I display it to command prompt the second ArrayList didnt display correctly aligned to each other.

This is my code:

```java
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class Arraylist{

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ArrayList<String> name = new ArrayList<String>();
        name.add("Darenz");
        name.add("Jason");
        name.add("Kurt");
        name.add("David");
        name.add("Damiar");

        ArrayList<Integer> grade = new ArrayList<Integer>();
        grade.add(11);
        grade.add(10);
        grade.add(12);
        grade.add(12);
        grade.add(10);

        for (int i = 0; 0 < name.size() && i < grade.size(); i++){
                System.out.println(name.get(i)+"          "+ grade.get(i));
            }
    }
}
```

This is the output of my code:

```
Darenz          11
Jason          10
Kurt          12
David          12
Damiar          10
```

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Try doing this inside your for loop:

```java
System.out.println(name.get(i)+"\t\t"+ grade.get(i));
```

The above makes two two tabs and aligns the text.
You could also use .printf() or .format() if you like.

Let me know if there's still a problem with it!

**Edit:** In case that the names are too long and the output still appears to be mis-aligned, adding more `\t`'s should work.

Comment: Outputting a tab character `\t` bears risk. The display of this output will vary and may be unexpected, based on where the string is used and how the system displays tab characters. For example, using this code example, even in the _ideal_ case, if your tab width is 4, and the longest name is 5+ longer than the shortest name, the columns will once again be misaligned. It appears you want to space your columns using the "space" character instead, and I believe that is a good idea. See my answer around format strings and column padding.

Comment: If you would like a failing test case, add people named `"Al"` and `"Abcdefghijklm"` to the list of names & grades. Whether you use `"    "`, `"\t"`, `"\t\t"`, `"\t\t\t"`, `"\t\t\t\t"`, etc., the text will still misalign unless the output is displayed with a huge tab width (12+). A suitable _general_ solution will vary padding based on the data itself. And unlike the tab character, the space character has a predictable width to be used for padding.

Comment: Or even "Al" and "Christopher".

Answer (score 3):

You will need to vary the spacing on each row because your first column does not have a consistent width. A typical way to do this is using `String.format(...)`, which uses a *format string* to print data according to a specific layout.

[The specification for a *format string* is here](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Formatter.html#syntax). For each piece of data, the format string will specify a *conversion*:

> The required conversion is a character indicating how the argument should be formatted. The set of valid conversions for a given argument depends on the argument's data type.

In this case, `name.get(i)` represents a `String`, so you want to use `%s` to represent that data.

Then you are looking for *width* in order to add spacing:

> The optional *width* is a positive decimal integer indicating the minimum number of characters to be written to the output.

> The width is the minimum number of characters to be written to the output. If the length of the converted value is less than the width then the output will be padded by '  ' ('\u0020') until the total number of characters equals the width. The padding is on the left by default. If the '-' flag is given, then the padding will be on the right. If the width is not specified then there is no minimum.

It looks like you might want a 13 character column, left-aligned, followed by a space, followed by an integer. So here is your format string: `"%-13s %d"`. And here is your final string after formatting:

`String.format("%-13s %d", name.get(i), grade.get(i))`

Comment: Sorry to let you know but this question was already answered (see the comments in the previous answer). This is why I asked @SansSuke to mark it as answered, so that other people don't waste their time on answering questions that have been answered already. 

(Upvoting because you did put in a lot of effort)
Sorry!

Comment: I did see your answer before beginning to write mine. I do not believe the accepted answer is suitable in a general case, and I would not accept it as fully correct on a school assignment.

Comment: @TheSj This is a better answer than yours.

Comment: @ScaryWombat I agree, however, the user didn't ask for all cases, they had asked for only that case. If you look at my original answer, I do include that they can use .format() to solve this problem, however, since the names were pretty short, I didn't bother using that method.

Comment: Even in the single specific case given (all entries have either 4, 5, or 6 characters), data will _still_ fail to align for certain tab widths.